# How do I add all the values with key "value" in the dict?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a dict like this:

```
{
    'first':{'value': 2, 'blah': 'ants'}, 
    'second':{'value': 5, 'blah': 'birds'}, 
    'third':{'value': 8, 'blah': 'cats'},
    'fourth':{'value': 10, 'blah': 'cats'}
}
```

I want the output to be 25 i.e(2+5+8+10)

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Have a look at [*Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) if you don't know how to iterate dictionary in Python.

Comment: You iterate over the dict and add the values together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sum()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum)) builtin function and iterate over dictionary values:

```
d = {
    'first':{'value': 2, 'blah': 'ants'},
    'second':{'value': 5, 'blah': 'birds'},
    'third':{'value': 8, 'blah': 'cats'},
    'fourth':{'value': 10, 'blah': 'cats'}
}

print(sum(v['value'] for v in d.values()))
```

OR (Thanks Gabor), if key `'value'` doesn't exists to get default value `0`:

```
print(sum(v.get('value', 0) for v in d.values()))
```

Prints:

```
25
```

Comment: I suggest to use `v.get('value',0)` to not have any exceptions thrown.

Comment: @GáborFekete Added to the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate by using below one,

```
cc={
'first':{'value': 2, 'blah': 'ants'},
'second':{'value': 5, 'blah': 'birds'},
'third':{'value': 8, 'blah': 'cats'},
'fourth':{'value': 10, 'blah': 'cats'}
```

}

```
dictionary = {}
counter = 0
sum = 0
for i in cc:
    dictionary[i] = counter
    datavalue = list(cc.values())[counter].values()[1]
    counter += 1
    sum += datavalue

print sum
```